# Does the Microsoft Lumia 950 come with headphones?

Tags: lumia-950

All of my previous Nokia Lumia phones (925, 930, 1020) came with headphones. Now that the branding has changed to Microsoft Lumia, I am wondering if the Microsoft Lumia 950 also comes with headphones. The [Tech Specs](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msaus/en_AU/pdp/Microsoft-Lumia-950-Unlocked/productID.326973700?icid=LumiaR_ModG_r20_1_950_11122015) only list:

> **In the box**
>
> - Microsoft Lumia 950
> - Product user guide
> - Battery
> - Charger
> - USB-C cable

Note that headphones are not listed.

Comment: If the "In the box" part doesn't list headphones, then it's a fair guess it doesn't come with headphones.

Comment: Down voter, please note that I asked and answered my own question for the benefit of others who may assume that headphones are included based on the established `Lumia` brand.

Comment: No they throw in an actual wall charger and a separate USB cable instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I bought a Microsoft Lumia 950 directly from the Microsoft online store.

**No headphones are included.**

Comment: Something to be wary of is that not all headphones seem to work either. The headphones that came with my Lumia 1020 do but they hurt my ears after a while due to the funny design. My Sennheiser's (annoyingly) don't work even though they did work with the 1020.