# What headset wiring compatability does the Lumia 950 have?

Tags: audio, lumia-950, headset

There [appears to be two predominant wiring standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_%28audio%29#TRRS_standards) for the same physical connector.

As the Lumia 950 [does not come with a supplied headset](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/12257/106), and there is no information in [its tech specs](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msuk/en_GB/pdp/productID.326061500?icid=icid_ww_catp_modg_phn_citytalk_120315ga) as to what wiring it supports, what wiring should I look for when buying a headset - i.e. Does the Lumia 950 only support OMTP, only AHJ, or does it support both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this Microsoft support article](http://web.archive.org/web/20160307163954/http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA136274) Lumia phones support the AHJ standard, except the Lumia 920 and 820 which *also* support OMTP.

The article makes no mention of newer models, so I pinged @LumiaHelp on Twitter to check if it's still up-to-date. They confirmed that it is, and that the Lumia 950 supports AHJ headsets.
(Update: unfortunately [the @LumiaHelp account has been closed](https://mspoweruser.com/microsoft-shutting-lumiahelp-localised-lumia-twitter-accounts-september) so their response is no longer available on Twitter and I can't find an archived version.)

If you have a headset that's wired according to the OMTP standard, you can use it with your Lumia 950 with a simple [AHJ-OMTP adapter](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00KU2KY0O).